# How do i get my fixed element to stand alone without going on top of the other content?

Tags: css, position, fixed

I have at the top of my page a div dedicated as a top bar. I want the position to be fixed so that it stays in the same place when scrolling. BUT.. once I apply the fixed positioning, all of the content moves up by about 30px (the size of the bar) and sits behind the bar making the header appear smaller in height than what it should be.

Once the css for position:fixed is removed from #topbar the content moves down to it's desired place
code via codepen: http://codepen.io/Hafkamp/pen/jabmE

css

```
#topbar{position:fixed}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the #topbar, add CSS:

```
#topbar{
    top:0;
}
```

Also, to the #header add:

```
#header{
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

This way, your #topbar will stick to the top of the page and the following html will be pushed down by 30px(the height of the #topbar)

Comment: Thanks mate ;) didn't realize i could still use the top property when the position is fixed. Thought that only applied to absolute. The header margin-top should have been obvious though. Cheers

Comment: No problem, try not to forget to vote up the correct answer :)

Comment: Yah I really would but stackoverflow only allows me to do this once I reach 15 rep points :/ I'll vote you up when I get there :)

Answer (score 0):

Just give the margib top to the header of 30 px